# Wrapping text inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I want to make sure that text can never expand my table, regardless of how long it is.  I allready have some PHP code limiting characters at 100 per cell, but I want to make sure that a long text string can never expand the table.  For example:

atextstringthislongwithoutanyspacescanexpandthewidthofmycellrightnow

Comment: what do you want the long text to do? wrap?, truncate?...

Answer (score 1):

`word-break: break-all` usually does the trick, however I remember having some problems in Chrome where long words would still not break correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If there are specific places you want to control, you could use [the wbr tag](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html).

Answer (score 0):

put a fixed width div inside the table cell, then put your text inside the div.

if this helps, please select the check mark next to my answer. thanks!